# No se puede conectar porque la identificación del host remoto ssh ha cambiado

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ssh

He reinstalado mi servidor y estoy recibiendo estos mensajes:

```sh
[user@hostname ~]$ ssh -p 2222 user@127.0.0.1
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
6e:45:f9:a8:af:38:3d:a1:a5:c7:76:1d:02:f8:77:00.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/hostname /.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts:4
RSA host key for pong has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Intenté eliminar todas las claves pertenecientes a 127.0.0.1 con:

```
ubu@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Downloads/Hozana$ ssh-keygen -R 127.0.0.1
Host 127.0.0.1 not found in /home/ubu/.ssh/known_hosts
ubu@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Downloads/Hozana$ ssh-keygen -R 127.0.0.1:2222
Host 127.0.0.1:2222 not found in /home/ubu/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Ambas me devuelven lo mismo.

Comment: Te está diciendo que la huella en discordia se encuentra en la línea 4 del archivo `/var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts`, y no en `/home/ubu/.ssh/known_hosts`. ¿Has probado a borrarla de allí? Tienes que agregar el archivo así: `ssh-keygen -R 127.0.0.1 -f /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts`

Comment: Por lo que veo el servidor "sssd" (System Security Services Daemon) es el que está recibiendo la huella dactilar errónea y aunque lo borres de ese archivo volverá a aparecer en cuanto la fuente de autenticación que estés usando vuelva a obtenerla. Si no puedes borrar la entrada con un simple `sed -i '4d' /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts` prueba a reiniciar o detener el servicio `sssd` mientras hagas las pruebas.